# rerender check - with same state of `useState` but not with same state of redux, why?

Tags: reactjs, redux, jsx, use-state

Here's the screensnapshot:

[image]

When I click 1,2, both won't cause rerender.
When once I click 3, clicking 1 does not cause rerender, and only clicking 2 will cause rerender, what's the reason?

Note that

```
 const { key1, key2 } = useSelector(({ obj: { key1, key2 } }) => ({
    key1,
    key2
  }));
```

This is purposely put there to cause rerender should there is any rerender check since `{key1,key2}` will always be different (it's object).

Below are codes:

Here's the `tryRerender.js`, notice the comments inside for important information

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

export default function TryRerender() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [state, setState] = useState(1);

  //purposely put here to cause rerender
  const { key1, key2 } = useSelector(({ obj: { key1, key2 } }) => ({
    key1,
    key2
  }));

  //this is rerendering
  const setSameState = (e) => {
    console.log("same local state");
    setState((state) => state);
  };

  //this is not rerendering, why?
  const setSameRedux = (e) => {
    console.log("same redux state");
    dispatch({ type: "same" });
  };

  const setDiffRedux = (e) => {
    console.log("different redux state");
    dispatch({ type: "diff" });
  };

  return (
    <>
      {console.log("rerender")}
      <button onClick={setSameState}>Same local State</button>
      <br />

      <button onClick={setSameRedux}>Same Redux State</button>

      <br />

      <button onClick={setDiffRedux}>Different Redux State</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

here's the `App.js`, notice comments inside too

```
import React from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import myStore from "./Redux";
import TryRerender from "./tryRerender";

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={myStore}>
      <TryRerender></TryRerender>
    </Provider>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Here's the `Redux.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import myStore from "./Redux";
import TryRerender from "./tryRerender";

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={myStore}>
      <TryRerender></TryRerender>
    </Provider>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Here's the `index.js`

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

[Try code at codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-water-de7nk6?file=/src/App.js:0-276)

My hypothesis

1. `onSelect` will be checked ONLY when there is different state from the point where `onSelect` is declared;
2. `setState` will trigger a state check, if `onSelect` is on same state, it skips check; otherwise it will always trigger a check.
3. dispatch same state will make `onSelect` skip check as well.

I delve into the source codes here could be the related ones:

> react-redux/src/hooks/useSelector.ts

https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/a2853bcf2e04e073ba2ac13e3bb48829edcc2b60/src/hooks/useSelector.ts#L34
https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/a2853bcf2e04e073ba2ac13e3bb48829edcc2b60/src/hooks/useSelector.ts#L53

> react-redux/src/utils/useSyncExternalStore.ts

https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/791e00945558eb1586d719b51666493276c8d63d/src/utils/useSyncExternalStore.ts#L2

> react/packages/use-sync-external-store/src/useSyncExternalStoreWithSelector.js

https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/6bce0355c3e4bf23c16e82317094230908ee7560/packages/use-sync-external-store/src/useSyncExternalStoreWithSelector.js#L75

Comment: What is there to re-render? You only have onclick handlers in your markup.

Comment: You can see the console message, when rerender it will give "rerender" @timotgl

Comment: Have you tried actually rendering `key1` and `key2` in the JSX? React might skip invoking the body of the function component if you're not using the values from `useSelector`.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* the first issue here is that you're creating a Redux store *inside* of the `<App>` component.  **Don't do that - you should *never* create a Redux store inside of a component!**

In particular, React will double-render components when inside of a `<StrictMode>` tag.  That means that *two* stores would get created here, because `<App>` would render twice.  So, it's very likely that components are creating an initial subscription to the *first* store, but then the dispatches would happen to the *second* store.

Try moving the store creation *outside* of `<App>` and see if that helps.

Comment: Hi thanks, I have modified it, and changed the questions to make it clearer